# sql select - combine the data from the column into one and run distinct on it

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

i have a table:

```
id    coach1    coach2    department    date
1       1         0           txt1       8/11/2010
2       3         0           txt2       1/11/2010
3       1         2           txt1       8/11/2010
4       3         1           txt1       8/11/2010
```

what i want to do is to get one column from both coaches, ignore the zeros and witout repeating the numbers of the coaches so the output of this example will be:

```
coach    department    date
  1          txt1       8/11/2010
  2          txt1       8/11/2010
  3          txt1       1/11/2010
```

so i used:

```
SELECT id,coach1 as coach,department,date FROM tblWinnings where coach1>0 UNION SELECT id,coach2 as coach,department,date FROM tblWinnings where coach2>0
```

but now i need to have it distinct by the coach column

how do i do that?

thanks!

Comment: Is there any logic to determine if coch 3 should be the one from id2 or the one with id4? The reason I ask is that they have different departments/dates

Comment: You have a schema error, which should be clear based on the field that you have coach1 and coach2 as field names. If you instead used a N:N join table to link these records to the coaches, you'd have much simpler SQL. However, previous to A2010, restricting the join table to only two coaches each is more complicated (though not impossible at the engine level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot remember the syntax for access but something like

```
select distinct coach from (
select coach1 as coach from tableX 
union all 
select coach2 as coach from tableX) 
where coach <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct coach1 as coach from tblName
union 
select coach2 from tblName
order by coach
```

If you only want the distinct values, don't use Union All (union without the All clause prevents duplicates)

Since you keep updating your question:  You're going to run into a problem if you want the values from the other fields, since they could be different depending on the one you use. (Latest? Earliest? Random?)

Answer (score 0):

```
create view coaches as
  select coach1 as coach
    from table
   where coach1 <> 0
union all
  select coach2 as coach
    from table
   where coach1 <> 0;

select distinct coach
  from coaches;
```

Comment: Can't "create view" in ms access

Comment: right - so what will i do :-) actualy i'm on ASP with MS ACCESS DB